# How do i run mongo shell outside my installation directory?

Tags: mongodb, cmd

Whenever I run mongo on command line i get

`'mongo' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.`

I'll have to change to my directory first to run mongo shell, which is pretty deep in my directory.

How do can I run mongo shell without changing my directory?

Comment: Did you tried to add the mongo installation directory to the PATH environment variable (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee537574(v=office.14).aspx) ?

Comment: Add inside ENV variable and create service if you don't want start from cmd every time.